# Deprecated: Non-static method AriKernel::init() should not be called statically in

Tags: php, deprecated

My server team showed me the following error log.

`Deprecated: Non-static method AriKernel::init() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/modules/mod_ariimageslider/mod_ariimageslider/kernel/class.AriKernel.php on line 103`

**Line 103**
 `AriKernel::init();`

I searched on google but I didn't find any solution. There is almost 100+ same deprecation error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So call it via object.. If you are migrating between versions, you should do that on local first.

Comment: Make `init()` method static or create the object of the `AriKernel` class and then call dynamic method of it. Third alternative doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know your class' code, however rule is simple, most of contemporary IDEs will allow you to choose only methods of proper types while typing:

```php
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public static function myStaticMethod()
    {
        echo 'This is static method';
    }

    public function myNONStaticMethod()
    {
        echo 'This is NON-static method';
    }
}

// call of static method
MyClass::myStaticMethod();

// call of NON static method
$object = new MyClass();
$object->myNONStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer has fixed my problem. There was a deprecation warning `PHP Deprecated: Non-static method` in a log file on `PHP 7.4`, but getting a critical error on `PHP 8.0.16`.

Comment: @TayyabChaudhary, that's correct, since `PHP 8.0.0` calling non-static methods results in fatal:  https://php.watch/versions/8.0/non-static-static-call-fatal-error